# System Execution Engine exception on object that passes null guard

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullreferenceexception, visual-studio-debugging

Hello can someone please explain me how can one object pass through a `NULL` guard then throws exception when trying to acess non-nullable field? (bool)

As you can see in the method above our object `response` of type `Node` is not null.Focus your attention on the `boolean` field `IsArray`  !!

[image]

Lets see what happens when our `response` enters the `Deserialize` method:

[image: Node is not null before entering Deserialize method]

```
                                   Passes null guard !!
```

[image]

Then crashes with `Null Reference Exception` on an `non-nullable field`.Exactly on  the field i said to focus: the `boolean` `IsArray`.

**Stack Trace**

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at redius.Node.get_Kind() in D:\Work\redius\core\redius\Internals\Resp\Node.cs:line 15
   at redius.Node.get_IsArray() in D:\Work\redius\core\redius\Internals\Resp\Node.cs:line 22
   at redius.Deserializer.List.Deserialize(Node node) in D:\Work\redius\core\redius\Internals\Formatter\Deserializer\Deserializer.List.cs:line 19}
```

Can someone please explain me how is this possible?Below is the `Node` type:

```
public abstract partial class Node : IEquatable<Node> {

        public enum Discriminator {
            String,
            Integer,
            Array
        }

        public Discriminator Kind => this.NodeKind;
        protected abstract Discriminator NodeKind { get; }

        public Node.Array AsArray => this as Node.Array;
        public Node.Integer AsInteger => this as Node.Integer;
        public Node.String AsString => this as String;

        public bool IsArray => this.Kind == Discriminator.Array;
        public bool IsString => this.Kind == Discriminator.Integer;
        public bool IsInteger => this.Kind == Discriminator.String;

        #region IRAW

        protected virtual ReadOnlyMemory<byte> GetRaw() {
            return new byte[] { };
        }

        #endregion

        public bool Equals(Node other) {
            if (this.Kind != other.Kind) {
                return false;
            }
            bool result;
            switch (other.Kind) {
                case Discriminator.Array: result = this.AsArray.Equals(other.AsArray); break;
                case Discriminator.Integer: result = this.AsInteger.Equals(other.AsInteger); break;
                case Discriminator.String: result = this.AsString.Equals(other.AsString); break;

                default: throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```

**P.S:** When the `Node` enters the `Deserialize` method something goes wrong with the debugger since i can't acess it (can not acess its fields) !

**P.S 2** If i try to add the following line in the `Deserializer` method :
`var values = node.GetType().GetFields().Select(x => x.GetValue(node));`
 the application enters a break state and i  get the following exception :
`System Execution Engine Exception`

Comment: Post the actual, full exception including the call stack. You can get that easily by calling `Exception.ToString()`. I'd bet call stack shows that the exception is thrown by the null guard of *another* thread. Throw an `ArgumentNullException` with an explanation instead of the generic `NullReferenceException()`, eg `throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node))`

Comment: Check my last line.I get an engine exception if i try to get the value of the fields.However the fields are present when entering the method as you can see in the first snippet.

Comment: The first *image* doesn't show any exceptions. *Please post the actual exception, including the call stack*. Posting the *name* of the exception doesn't help at all. And *do* use the appropriate exception, `ArgumentNullException`. You *don't* need to access any fields, just log the result of `Exception.ToString()` in your exception handler

Comment: Well the first image is posted to show you that the object in case is not null before it enters the `Deserialize` method ! It somehow becomes `NULL` inside the method and throws exception.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at a *different* thread? Post the exception please. It's impossible to reproduce the problem or guess what's wrong from screenshots and incomplete information. Without the call stack it's impossible which code path resulted in the exception

Comment: I do not have multiple threads in this application.

Comment: Did you check the call stack snippet you posted? The exception is thrown by the `redius.Node.Kind` getter. Not by `node.IsArray` or the guard clause. The getter calls the abstract NodeKind property which isn't shown here. Without knowing what the actual implementation of NodeKind is, only  you can find the problem by debugging the code when the exception occurs. You didn't post the *full* exception either. There may be an inner exception thrown/rethrown by `NodeKind`. Just use `Exception.ToString()` to get the entire exception, inner exceptions and all call stacks and post that.

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces the problem. Right now people have to guess a lot - what the actual exception is, where it was thrown, what code was actually called, what the property values are

Comment: Ok i have solved it.The problem was not related.I was using the `ILGenerator` and to generate the `ProcessAsync` method and i have mistaken the return type.It can be closed.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, Since you have resoled this issue, would you please convert your comment to the answer? This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we close this thread :).